# best lithium ion secondary battery (3A, 3V)

Tags: battery

Are there any reasonably priced standard lithium ion batteries that comes closest to:
either **3A (discharge limit)** and **3 volts** **(x16 batteries)**.
or **4A (discharge limit)** and **4 volts** **(x12 batteries)**.

They can be in any size. (18650, 18350, 18500, 26650, 1/2 AA, 2/3 AA, AA, C or D, etc, etc...) Although I prefer bigger ones, since they have more cycles and longer run time (more time before they run out of juice).

I have been searching everywhere and have been unable to find a lithium ion battery that comes close enough to that criteria. Any help?

Comment: I had serious troubles even on ebay/amazon/etc to find batteries with a voltage not 1.5V (1.2V) or 5V.